# app auto start not working after device rebooted(android 9)

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am using this Cordova plugin for Cordova app auto start after the device rebooted.
https://github.com/ToniKorin/cordova-plugin-autostart

I checked many version and found that android 7.1.2 version is working properly but another version like android 9 not working.

is there any other plugin available for this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I used to have the same problem.

When i used this plugin for the first time https://github.com/ToniKorin/cordova-plugin-autostart.

It only worked for me in debug mode (Android 9 emulator) but in a real android 9 device phone it doesnt worked.

For this to work in a real device (android 9) you will need to use this ionic official plugin:
https://github.com/NeoLSN/cordova-plugin-android-permissions

You have to give permission 'RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED' to the app to autostart.

SOURCE: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED.

It helped me to solve the problem I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone looking here--

1. As @dudu.sck says, you need to add the RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED permission to your config.xml :

```
<config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/*">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
</config-file>
```

2. The **user** needs to enable the "Allow display over other apps" permission for your app in particular.  I don't know why, but it's true.

These are all I've needed to do for autostart to work on Android 11.  **NOTE:** Your app might take a minute or more to autostart after the boot is complete, **and** after you unlock the screen.